# How to increment the value of a variable in a loop for insert sql statement using pyodbc

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyodbc

I'm attempting to pull employee timecard data from an API and subsequently insert it into a sql database.  I want the code to look at the data, isolate the punches in and out for a specific date and then insert them into the sql database.  The only catch is that the database requires a sequence number "SEQ_NO" to indicate which punch of the day it was to account for breaks, lunches etc. so I want it to loop increasing the sequence number by 1 without executing the header insert more than once for the same employee(eventually "kelly walton" and "080098" will be replaced with variables so that this can execute for every employee in the data set.

I've tried just about every variable incrementation method I've found on stack overflow and I cannot get it to work.  for loops, while loops if, elif statements you name it and I can't get anything to work. This is just one version of the code. To clarify the issue is that no matter which type of loop I try to use it tries to duplicate some of the values either the header query or the punch data resulting in errors in the sql database.

```
today = ('2019-06-05')
with open('timepunches.json', 'r') as f:
    timepunches_dict = json.load(f)
for punch in timepunches_dict:
    punch_in = punch['PunchInDateTime']
    punch_out = punch['PunchOutDateTime']
    punch_in_sql = punch_in.replace('T', ' ')
    punch_out_sql = punch_out.replace('T', ' ')
    if today in punch_in_sql:
        #print(punch_in_sql, punch_out_sql)
        cnx = pyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server};server=MY_server;database=my_db;uid=****;pwd=****')
        cursor = cnx.cursor()
        sequence_number = 1
            if sequence_number == 1:
                sql_insert_header_query = ''' INSERT INTO my_db.dbo.SY_TIMCRD_HDR
                    (STR_ID, USR_ID, TIMCRD_DAT, USR_NAM) VALUES ('M-MAC', '080098', '2019-06-05 00:00:00.000', 'Kelly Walton')'''
                sql_timecard_data = '''INSERT INTO my_db.dbo.SY_TIMCRD_LIN
                    (STR_ID, USR_ID, TIMCRD_DAT, SEQ_NO, CLCK_IN_TIM) VALUES ('M-MAC', '080098', [dbo].[fnDateOnly]('%s'), '%s', [dbo].[fnTimeOnly]('%s'))'''
                cursor.execute(sql_insert_header_query)
                cursor.execute(sql_timecard_data % (today, sequence_number, punch_in_sql))
                sequence_number+=1
            elif sequence_number == 2:
                sql_timecard_data = '''INSERT INTO my_db.dbo.SY_TIMCRD_LIN
                    (STR_ID, USR_ID, TIMCRD_DAT, SEQ_NO, CLCK_OUT_TIM) VALUES ('M-MAC', '080098', [dbo].[fnDateOnly]('%s'), '%s', [dbo].[fnTimeOnly]('%s'))'''
                cursor.execute(sql_insert_header_query)
                cursor.execute(sql_timecard_data % (today, sequence_number, punch_out_sql))
                sequence_number+=1            
        cnx.commit()
        cnx.close()
```

I thought this would increase 'sequence_number' to 2 and execute the next part. and I intended to add more statements once I got this part working.

Edit: This is the JSON data in 'timepunches.json' which may be helpful.

```
[{"JobCodeId": null, 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInImageUrl": "", 
    "LocationName": "", 
    "PunchInNotes": "", 
    "PunchOutLongitude": null, 
    "PunchOutLatitude": null, 
    "Employee": 
        {"Username": "starlord", 
        "EmployeeId":"080097", 
        "FirstName": "Peter", 
        "LastName": "Quill", 
        "ProfileMiniImageUrl": "https://buddypunchapp.blob.core.windows.net/profileminipics/new_employee_face2.jpg", 
        "Email": "starlord@email.com", 
        "FullName": "Peter Quill", 
        "Id": 346968, 
        "IsActive": true}, 
    "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-10T10:00:00", 
    "BreakMinutes": 0, 
    "Hours": 2.0, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "OverTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "JobCodeName": "", 
    "PunchInIpAddress": "", 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "", 
    "PunchOutIpAddress": "", 
    "PunchOutImageUrl": "", 
    "PunchInLongitude": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusId": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusName": null, 
    "PTOHours": null, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-10T08:00:00", 
    "PunchOutNotes": "", 
    "PTOEarningCodeId": null, 
    "Id": 12971600, 
    "PunchInLatitude": null, 
    "LocationId": null, 
    "Duration": "02:00:00", 
    "RegularHours": 2.0}, 

    {"JobCodeId": null, 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInImageUrl": "", 
    "LocationName": "", 
    "PunchInNotes": "", 
    "PunchOutLongitude": null, 
    "PunchOutLatitude": null, 
    "Employee": {
        "Username": "starlord", 
        "EmployeeId": "080097", 
        "FirstName": "Peter", 
        "LastName": "Quill", 
        "ProfileMiniImageUrl": "https://buddypunchapp.blob.core.windows.net/profileminipics/new_employee_face2.jpg", 
        "Email": "starlord@email.com", 
        "FullName": "Peter Quill", 
        "Id": 346968, 
        "IsActive": true}, 
    "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-10T12:00:00", 
    "BreakMinutes": 0, 
    "Hours": 1.75, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "OverTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "JobCodeName": "", 
    "PunchInIpAddress": "", 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "", 
    "PunchOutIpAddress": ", 
    "PunchOutImageUrl": "", 
    "PunchInLongitude": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusId": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusName": null, 
    "PTOHours": null, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-10T10:15:00", 
    "PunchOutNotes": "", 
    "PTOEarningCodeId": null, 
    "Id": 12971609, 
    "PunchInLatitude": null, 
    "LocationId": null, 
    "Duration": "01:45:00", 
    "RegularHours": 1.75}, 

    {"JobCodeId": null, 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInImageUrl": "", 
    "LocationName": "", 
    "PunchInNotes": "", 
    "PunchOutLongitude": null, 
    "PunchOutLatitude": null, 
    "Employee": {
        "Username": "starlord", 
        "EmployeeId": "080097", 
        "FirstName": "Peter", 
        "LastName": "Quill", 
        "ProfileMiniImageUrl": "https://buddypunchapp.blob.core.windows.net/profileminipics/new_employee_face2.jpg", 
        "Email": "starlord@email.com", 
        "FullName": "Peter Quill", 
        "Id": 346968, 
        "IsActive": true}, 
    "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-10T15:00:00", 
    "BreakMinutes": 0, 
    "Hours": 2.0, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "OverTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "JobCodeName": "", 
    "PunchInIpAddress": "", 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "", 
    "PunchOutIpAddress": "", 
    "PunchOutImageUrl": "", 
    "PunchInLongitude": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusId": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusName": null, 
    "PTOHours": null, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-10T13:00:00", 
    "PunchOutNotes": "", 
    "PTOEarningCodeId": null, 
    "Id": 12971618, 
    "PunchInLatitude": null, 
    "LocationId": null, 
    "Duration": "02:00:00", 
    "RegularHours": 2.0}, 

    {"JobCodeId": null, 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInImageUrl": "", 
    "LocationName": "", 
    "PunchInNotes": "", 
    "PunchOutLongitude": null, 
    "PunchOutLatitude": null, 
    "Employee": {
        "Username": "starlord", 
        "EmployeeId": "080097", 
        "FirstName": "Peter", 
        "LastName": "Quill", 
        "ProfileMiniImageUrl": "https://buddypunchapp.blob.core.windows.net/profileminipics/new_employee_face2.jpg", 
        "Email": "starlord@email.com", 
        "FullName": "Peter Quill", 
        "Id": 346968, 
        "IsActive": true}, 
    "PunchOutDateTime": "2019-06-10T17:00:00", 
    "BreakMinutes": 0, 
    "Hours": 1.75, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "OverTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "DoubleTimeHours": 0.0, 
    "JobCodeName": "", 
    "PunchInIpAddress": "", 
    "PunchInApprovalStatusName": "Changed By Manager", 
    "PTOEarningCodeAbbr": "", 
    "PunchOutIpAddress": "", 
    "PunchOutImageUrl": "", 
    "PunchInLongitude": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusId": null, 
    "BreakApprovalStatusName": null, 
    "PTOHours": null, 
    "PunchOutApprovalStatusId": 4, 
    "PunchInDateTime": "2019-06-10T15:15:00", 
    "PunchOutNotes": "", 
    "PTOEarningCodeId": null, 
    "Id": 12971630, 
    "PunchInLatitude": null, 
    "LocationId": null, 
    "Duration": "01:45:00", 
    "RegularHours": 1.75}]
```

Comment: I would define `cnx` outside of your `for` loop, as it's quite inefficient to re-build the connection on every iteration

Comment: `If/Elif` is "do this, or that" so it's 1 and it does this and increments it to 2, the next iteration of the loop, it sets it back to 1 and checks if it's 1 again...

Comment: I'll certainly build the cnx outside of the loop that's a good call.  But I'm more concerned with the part of the code that's broken and I'll worry more about efficiency after I get it working.

Comment: @tgikal how would you recommend executing what I'm trying to do then?

Comment: What is `[dbo].[fnDateOnly]`? And you do not explain what is the problem with current code. You say *I can't get anything to work* but this is vague. Does this mean NOTHING or wrong data appends?

Comment: It was trying to append the same data twice which was throwing an error due to the db not allowing duplicate keys in the header table.  Turns out I accidentally copied the header insert query into the second part of the loop which is why it was happening twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following adjustment to your process using `enumerate()` during loop for a sequence number and importantly employing [parameterization](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Binding-Parameters) and not string interpolation.

```
# VARIABLES
today = '2019-06-05'

# OPEN CONNECTION AND CURSOR
cnx = pyodbc.connect('driver={SQL Server};server=MY_server;database=my_db;uid=****;pwd=****')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# PREPARED STATEMENTS
sql_insert_header_query = '''INSERT INTO my_db.dbo.SY_TIMCRD_HDR (STR_ID, USR_ID, TIMCRD_DAT, USR_NAM) 
                             VALUES ('M-MAC', ?, ?, ?)
                          '''

sql_timecard_data = '''INSERT INTO my_db.dbo.SY_TIMCRD_LIN (STR_ID, USR_ID, TIMCRD_DAT, SEQ_NO, CLCK_IN_TIM) 
                       VALUES ('M-MAC', ?, [dbo].[fnDateOnly](?), ?, [dbo].[fnTimeOnly](?))
                    '''

with open('timepunches.json', 'r') as f:
    timepunches_dict = json.load(f)

for i, punch in enumerate(timepunches_dict):
    punch_in = punch['PunchInDateTime']
    punch_out = punch['PunchOutDateTime']
    punch_in_sql = punch_in.replace('T', ' ')
    punch_out_sql = punch_out.replace('T', ' ')

    emp_id = punch['Employee']['EmployeeId']
    emp_name = punch['Employee']['FullName']

    if today in punch_in_sql:
        #print(punch_in_sql, punch_out_sql)

        if i == 0:
            # ONLY RUN FOR FIRST ITERATION 
            cursor.execute(sql_insert_header_query, (emp_id, today, emp_name))
            cnx.commit()     

        # RUN FOR ALL ITERATIONS
        cursor.execute(sql_timecard_data, (emp_id, today, i+1, punch_in_sql))        
        cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/FTRO4737) *(minus database objects)*

Comment: This makes sense to me for the most part and is much cleaner, however, what would be the best way to start i at 1 as 0 is an invalid seq_no as well as I'm now getting the error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/micah/Desktop/Buddy Punch/employeeget.py", line 96, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql_insert_header_query, (emp_id, today, emp_name))
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The cursor's connection has been closed.`

This still executes the header query and one timecard query but then it fails and I get the above error.

Comment: It seems that i is not incrementing as well since I'm getting a sql error for a duplicate key value for SEQ_NO.

Comment: Without data, I cannot help much. But if *timepunches_dict* has more than 1 element, then `i` certainly increments starting from zero. You can add 1 to the `i` for each cursor call. See edit. Please clean out table data prior to running this code to avoid conflicts with existing sequences.

Comment: I added the JSON code to the original post to give you a better idea. It does have a lot of repeated data.

Comment: See edit. For whatever reason, my edit per last comment last night did not show up. Apparently the *emp_id* and *emp_name* can be retrieved inside json. I even add an online demo printing out the data to be inserted.

Comment: Well I've encountered a new issue that I hadn't expected and since your solution was so good I thought I might ask you again.  If the JSON data contains more than one days worth i.e. the 18th, 19th etc then the sequence number will start at one if todays date were the 19th for example. leaving out the header. I thought maybe I could create a dictionary that would extract only the data for the given day I could then run it through this loop problem solved. but I'm getting the error ```TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str``` do you know a good way to bypass this?  dict code below:

Comment: ```python
<br>

for date in parsed:
    date_dict={}
    date_dict['PunchInDateTime']=date.get('PunchInDateTime').split('T', 1)[0]

    if date_dict['PunchInDateTime'] == today:
        date_dict['Employee']=date.get('Employee').get('EmployeeId')
        date_dict['EmployeeName']=date.get('Employee').get('FullName')
        date_dict['PunchInDateTime']=date.get('PunchInDateTime')
        date_dict['PunchOutDateTime']=date.get('PunchOutDateTime')
```

Comment: See this update [demo](https://rextester.com/ULQ3310) adding another incremental variable, *j* with helper, *curr_date*. To demonstrate, I change last two *PunchInDateTime* to a different date: 12th.

Comment: This looks closer but what I'm trying to do is exclude all data that ISN'T the current date. So the output from this code is:
```python

('080098', '2019-06-10', u'Peter Quill')
('080098', '2019-06-10', 1, u'2019-06-10 08:00:00', u'2019-06-10 10:00:00')
('080098', '2019-06-10', 2, u'2019-06-10 10:15:00', u'2019-06-10 12:00:00')
('080098', '2019-06-10', 1, u'2019-06-12 13:00:00', u'2019-06-10 15:00:00')
('080098', '2019-06-10', 2, u'2019-06-12 15:15:00', u'2019-06-10 17:00:00')
```
Let's say it's the 19th. the only out put I want from the JSON data is:

Comment: ```python
(u'080097', u'2019-06-19', u'Peter Quill')
(u'080097', u'2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 08:00:00', u'2019-06-19 09:16:00')
(u'080097', u'2019-06-19', 2, u'2019-06-19 13:43:00', u'2019-06-19 16:43:00')
```

Comment: But original solution maintains an `if` condition to select on current date: `if today in punch_in_sql:`.

Comment: Yep, what I don't understand is why your output from rextester is different than mine.

your output is correct:
```json
080098 2019-06-10 Peter Quill
080098 2019-06-10 1 2019-06-10 08:00:00
080098 2019-06-10 2 2019-06-10 10:15:00
```
mine is missing the first output:
```json
(u'080097', '2019-06-19', 1, u'2019-06-19 08:00:00')
(u'080097', '2019-06-19', 2, u'2019-06-19 13:43:00')
```
Is it because the data format is different?  I'm taking the json data directly from the API and parsed = json.loads(data)

I even compared the code in a difference checker and its the same.

Comment: I changed the data in your demo to the data I have coming in to 'parsed' and the same issue arises [demo](https://rextester.com/TXGE66245) and both are in Python 3.  I'm not sure why changing the data but the same format would do this

Comment: It is because previous code assumes the header is always on very first dictionary of json regardless of date. But you condition on date with `if today in punch_in_sql: `. To fix, ignore all use of `i` (no more `enumerate`) and use `j`: `if j == 1:` https://rextester.com/GGB76730

Comment: Dude, you are the man, You deserve a thousand upvotes.  Thanks for all your help.